# "Reviews for current version" app store

Tags: ios, app-store

For apps in the app store, there are reviews for the current version, and then 'all reviews'. It appears that the average rating you are given is only for current version, is that correct?

Is it then better to release fewer updates?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app reviews and releases and not programming.

Comment: OK. Is there a better stack exchange site to post on for this type of thing?

Comment: Apple's Developer forums would be a good place I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.  The average rating is only for your current version.  The release cycle for your app will depend on your App Store strategy.  You need to look at how quickly you get ratings, how important ratings are for your app (generally very important), how import fast iterations are, getting user feedback, etc.  The right strategy will differ based on what your app and what your goals with it are.